# show stimulsoft report in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, stimulsoft

I am new to Stimulsoft Reports and I am struggling here. I cannot display the data set in the report. I created a simple Report.mrt file but it is empty.this what I have done so far...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = GetTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("office");
        ds.Tables.Add(table);
        ds.Namespace = "y";
        ds.Prefix = "x";
        stiReport1.RegData("MyDataSet", ds);
        stiReport1.Load("D:\\Report.mrt");
        stiReport1.Show();
    }

    public DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        return table;
    }
```

this doesnt display anything and I am not sure what to do from here. Should I add some text fields to the Report.mrt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would move the `stiReport1.Load` before the `stiReport1.RegData`.
Then you should compile the report

```
stiReport1.Load("D:\\Report.mrt");
stiReport1.RegData("MyDataSet", ds);
stiReport1.Dictionary.Synchronize();
stiReport1.Compile();
stiReport1.Show(true);
```